# How to Reduce Azure Durable Function verbose and information logging

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-durable-functions

In an Azure Durable Functions .NET project there are certain verbose and information logs in the log stream that I'd like to exclude or reduce. I have adjusted the log level in the host.json file, but some logs persist.

**host.json attempt:**

```
 { 
 "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "DurableTask.Core": "Information",
      "Host.Triggers.DurableTask": "Information"         
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2023-11-21T04:18:40Z   [Information]   planfunctionappname-control-00: Skipping ownership lease aquiring for planfunctionappname-control-00
2023-11-21T04:18:40Z   [Information]   planfunctionappname-control-01: Skipping ownership lease aquiring for planfunctionappname-control-01
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   Scheduling new RunOrchestrator orchestration with instance ID 'f5bba18be567ee4332e268526d023' and 0 bytes of input data.
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   Fetched instance status for f5bba18be2e54b699ed42e268526d023
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   Sending [ExecutionStarted] message to planfunctionappname-control-01 for instance 'f5bba18be2e54b699ed42e268526d023'
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   f5bba18be2e54b699ed42e268526d023: Updated Instances table and set the runtime status to 'Pending'
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   Waiting for instance 'f5bba18be2e54b699ed42e268526d023' to complete, fail, or terminate.
2023-11-21T04:19:00Z   [Information]   Fetched instance status for f5bba18be2e54b699ed42e268526d023
```

How can I exclude or reduce certain logs in Azure Durable Functions, including configurations or settings?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=csharp-inproc#functions-20), to reduce verbose logging of Durable Azure Function, change the setting to `"Warning"` or `"Error"`instead of `"Information"`.

- Modify the `host.json` configuration as shown below:

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "DurableTask.Core": "Warning",
      "DurableTask.AzureStorage": "Warning",
      "Host.Triggers.DurableTask": "Warning",
      "Function.Function1_HttpStart": "Information" //logging all the Function1_HttpStart logs.
    }
  }
}
```

**Portal:**

I could reduce my Durable Function's logs as shown below:

[image]

- Running the query in `FunctionApp=>Application Insights=>Logs`:

```
union isfuzzy=true availabilityResults,requests,exceptions,pageViews,traces,customEvents,dependencies
    | where timestamp > datetime("2023-11-26T09:14:56.937Z") and timestamp < datetime("2023-11-27T09:14:56.937Z")| order by timestamp desc| take 100
```

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)